# Behavior of PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER on iOS

Tags: ios, pthreads

Assuming there are a few classes, each using something like the following code to protect their area.

```
static pthread_mutex_t _mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
[..]
pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
//some code
pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
```

The question:
Do all these classes share the same mutex (so if s/o locks the mutex no one else will be able to access the protected area). Or does every `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` create a new mutex?

Literature seems to be ambiguous about this topic, depending on the system PTHREADS is running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` (or even Pthreads) and cannot be system dependent.

This is a basic C++ language question. You're using a `static` variable so there is only one of it.  You haven't shown enough code to know if it's a static member of a class (so there's one `_mutex` per class type, not per object) or a global static (so there's one `_mutex` per file).